# Reading in text file with time column which is separated by commas?

Tags: python, pandas, txt

I have a txt-file with data that looks like this

```
A,B,C,Time
xyz,1,MN,14/11/20 17:20:08,296000000
tuv,0,ST,30/12/20 11:11:18,111111111
```

I read the data in using this code:

```
df = pd.read_csv('path/to/file',delimiter=',')
```

Because of my time column it does not work correctly because `Time` is separated through a comma. How can I solve this and how can I make it work even in the case that I have multiple columns with such a time format?

I would like to get a datframe which looks like this:

```
 A B C Time
 xyz 1 MN 14/11/20 17:20:08,296000000
 tuv 0 ST 30/12/20 11:11:18,111111111
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What is your desire output?

Comment: Your input isn't well-formed. A much better fix is to disambiguate the input before attempting to read it in. Can you change whatever produces this data to use a different delimiter (e.g. tab or semicolon), or add double quotes around the time field to turn this into valid CSV?

Comment: @tripleee: You are right. I have to export it in another way from my SQL database. I will look for a solution. Thanks a lot for your hint!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `reset_index()` method,`apply()` method and `drop()` method:

```
df=df.reset_index()
df['Time']=df[['C','Time']].astype(str).apply(','.join,1)
df=df.drop(columns=['C'])
df.columns=['A','B','C','Time']
```

Now If you print `df` you will get desired output:

```
    A       B   C   Time
0   xyz     1   MN  14/11/20 17:20:08,296000000
1   tuv     0   ST  30/12/20 11:11:18,111111111
```

Now If you wish to convert it back to txt file then use:

```
df.to_csv('filename.txt',sep='|',index=False)
```

**Note:** you can't use `','` and `' '` as `sep` parameter because it creates the same problem when you try to load your txt/csv file

Comment: Thanks, it solves this particular problem! But when I have multiple time columns with commas than the manual work will be more as well. Hmm, I think I have to try to export the data in another way from my SQL Database.

Comment: When you have multiple time column then make changes in this method accordingly...or as per your wish you can try to export the data in another way from your SQL Database